# What does the iteration limit warning message I get when using ordinal::clmm mean?

Tags: r, mixed-model, ordinal-data

I am running the following CLMM model in R Studio (version 4.3.1):

> incr_clmm <- clmm(OLR_Response ~ Distance + Species + (1|Bird_ID), data=olr_increm)

I am able to run it but I get the following warning message:

> Warning message: `In update.uC(rho): step factor reduced below minimum when updating the random effects at iteration 28`

To give some context, I have behavioral data on 35 captive birds (35 unique Bird_IDs), of which 20 are the species, brown-headed cowbird (BHCO), and 15 are the species, red-winged blackbird (RWBL). Birds were exposed to an impulsive noise at varying distances (15-495 m, at 15 m increments) and their behavioral response was categorized by severity:

- 0 = remained relaxed
- 1 = increased vigilance, or
- 2 = elicited startle response.

We wanted to evaluate the behavioral responses (0 = relaxed, 1 = vigilance, or 2 = startled) to the impulsive noise as a function of distance from the detonation location (15–495m) in RWBL and BHCO with bird ID as a random effect, thus we chose to use a cumulative link mixed model.

What implications does this warning have on my results? Can proceed, or is this a major red flag?

**Current code:**

```
incr_clmm <- clmm(OLR_Response ~ Distance + Species + (1|Bird_ID), 
                  data=olr_increm
                  )
```

**Current warning:**

> `Warning message: In update.uC(rho): step factor reduced below minimum when updating the random effects at iteration 28`

I have tried this very model as a clm:

```
incr_clm <- clm(OLR_Response ~ Distance + Species, data=olr_increm)
```

and I do not get the warning message. Does this mean the warming is related to the random effect in some way? I have performed a likelihood ratio test and have concluded that the model truly does benefit from the inclusion of the random effect, so removing it is not a solution.

If this requires code to answer, please let me know and I will provide a reproducible example.

Comment: This is diffcult to investigate without data. You could try with different (than the default) starting values.

Comment: Personally I feel this would not have needed to be closed. While it is formulated in R, it's not really about coding and more about the algorithm. I answered straightforward regarding the issue and the code, but I actually don't understand everything about cumulative link mixed models and how the likelihood is optimized. It is still interesting to explain when why and how this situation occurs and that has nothing to do with coding and much more with understanding the algorithm and the mathematics. For example does the Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature mentioned by Harrell play a role?

Comment: ... I have a feeling that I can get around R and I have answered with that capacity. But I feel that the question is not fully answered (at least not most elegantly) and requires more statistical expertise than what I have (and it is not about debugging or coding). While providing an answer to this question, I was still puzzled about the situation and wondering how this error occurs. Why would clmm require such strong reduction in the stepsize? Is it because the likelihood is non-convex? If that is the case, then why is it non-convex? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

The related relevant code is in this function
https://github.com/runehaubo/ordinal/blob/master/src/utilityFuns.c

```
lineIter = 0;
//  simple line search, i.e. step halfing:
while(funValueTry > *funValue) {
  stepFactor *= 0.5;
  for(j = 0; j < *nu; j++)
    u[j] += stepFactor * step[j];
  funValueTry = d_nll(u, *nu, grFac, *stDev, o1, o2, *nx, eta1,
                      eta2, eta1Fix, eta2Fix, sigma, pr,
                      weights, *lambda, link);
  lineIter++;
  if(*trace)
    Trace(i+1+innerIter, stepFactor, *funValue, *maxGrad,
          u, *nu, 0);
  if(lineIter > *maxLineIter){
    *conv = -2;
    return ;
  }
  innerIter++;
}
```

The gradient descent performs a line search along the direction of optimal descent. It does this by itteratively halving the segment untill a point with a lower function value is found. The warning is given when `conv == -2`, that is when the step is such small that after `maxLineIter` steps of halving the segment there is still no improvement and the while loop is exited manualy instead of based on the condition `funValueTry > *funValue`.

I guess that if the function converges anyway, then this warning should be no problem. It indicates that the function has places where a Newton-Rhapson updating step has diverging behaviour (after the step the function value is larger instead of smaller) that can not be reduced by reducing the step size.

Comment: With the `ordinal:clmm2` function I needed to add this argument to solve one numerical integration problem: `nAGQ=7`.